# How may I echo all parameters with greater than 2 characters in bash?

Tags: bash

I have the following

```
#!/bin/bash
function f1 ()
{
  echo "all parameters with more than 2 characters"
}
f1 123 45 6789
```

I need to do something with parameters that have characters that are greater than 2. Can I echo them **without expanding** "$@" to a loop then doing checks with `wc -c`
In this case, I need to output `123 6789`

Comment: You can't do it without a loop. Even the solutions suggested here, use an implicit loop (represented by one or more pipes). However you do not need `wc` to count the number of characters in a variable. If you have a variable `V`, `${#V}` gives you the number of characters in this variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
f1(){
     tr -s " " "\n" <<< "$@"| grep ...|tr -s "\n" " "
}
```

Comment: Watch out for those crazy edge case testers that put newlines in data: `f1 $'foo\nbarbaz' arg2 3`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, here space would also be a problem.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yup I also see what you are both talking about

Comment: `printf '%s\0' "$@" | awk -vRS='\0' -vORS=' ' 'length>2'` (if no newline can use `\n` in the printf and omit/default RS)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to *expand* `$@` but you should loop over it:

```
for arg in "$@"
do
  [ "${#arg}" -gt 2 ] && printf '%s\n' "$arg"
done
```

The `${#arg}` code asks for the length (in bytes) of `$arg`.

Comment: Less typing, but same thing: `for arg do [ "${#arg}" -gt 2 ] && echo "$arg"; done`

Comment: @Jeff-SchaIler I had done than but that loop expands $@ which I didnt want

Comment: Bret, you want to check the length of each parameter, so I'm not sure how you'll get "there" without expanding $@.  I see you accepted Ipor's answer, which is fine, but their answer *also* expands "$@".

Comment: @BretJoseph You can not go through the elements of `$@` without looping over them. It's funny that you accepted an answer that not only expands `$@` but also makes several copies of its data and uses no fewer than three external utilities.

Comment: @JeffSchaller `s/echo/printf '%s\n'/` on my comment.

Comment: That works, @Kusalananda -- *and* it has the side benefit of *not* containing the string `$@`! :)

Comment: I was just looking for another method which doesn't use a loop. But thanks

Comment: @BretJoseph If the purpose was to be _efficient_, calling even a single external utility would be slower than Jeff's loop.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree

Answer (score 1):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
f1() print -r -- ${(M)@:#???*}
```

`${array:#pattern}` is to remove from the expansion of the array the elements that match the pattern (an extension over the `${var#pattern}`/`${var##pattern}` ksh operators). With the `M` parameter expansion flag (for *matched*), that does the reverse and only retain the ones that match.

Answer (score 0):

No external command (`wc`) necessary; try to use "Parameter Expansion / Parameter length" in the loop.

Comment: Suprisinglly when I ran `shellcheck` it actually asked me if I had tried ${#variable} now I understand what it means. Thanks